# Boolean operators in if statement not working

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain what's happening here? I'm trying to use the javascript `!!` (double-bang) operator [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) in conjunction with [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) (I'm storing 0 and 1 values and testing for truthiness, but I also need a missing key to be false, hence the undefined at the start.

Although it echos to the console as false when typecast, it doesn't in the 'if' statement.

```
var foo = undefined;

// outputs undefined
console.log(foo)

// typecast to non-inverted boolean 
console.log(!!foo);

if (!!foo) {
    console.log("If was false before, why won't this execute?");
}​ else {
    console.log("It didn't work");
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Produces:

```
undefined
false
It didn't work
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YAAA7/
(Chrome v 23.0.1271.97 & Firefox 16.0.1, OS X 10.8.2)

**Edit - corrected code:**

(The previous 'if' statement was just evaluating as false, so that branch would never run.)

```
var foo = false;

// outputs undefined
console.log(foo)

// typecast to non-inverted boolean 
console.log(!!foo);

if (!!foo == false) {
    console.log("Matches for foo undefined, foo = 0 and foo = false");
} else {
    console.log("Matches for foo = 1 and foo = true");
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YAAA7/1/

Comment: Well, `!!foo` is `false`, as you say, so the `else` branch will be taken. This is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: In one of the answer's comments, someone noted, correctly, that '!!' is not an operator--it's two '!' operators.

Comment: It's the oposite of the oposite of what the value of the variable.

Comment: @AlexMA In that case would say it's better practice to write `Boolean(foo)` instead of `!!foo`?

Comment: @williamt Yes, it's probably better practice if the code is likely to be edited by those who aren't familiar with the notation.  But some programmers enjoy throwing in a stylistic flourish once in a while, especially if it reduces the number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = undefined;
```

`foo` will return true.  Because, in JavaScript "", undefined, 0, NaN, false and null are considered falsey values.

http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls:_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN .

From your code:

```
var foo = undefined; //false

console.log(!!foo); // !!foo = false;

if(!!foo) { //false
  console.log("It will not come because the condition fails");
}else{
    console.log("Else Part");
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

That is expected behavior.  If you double not false, you get false.  This ,`!`l is a not operator. This ,`!!`, is two not operators.  The double not operator is sometimes used to cast to the Boolean type.

```
! false === true
!! false === false
```